# AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, oauth-2.0

I am trying to do some things with a Cron.yaml
My cron works fine, but the authentication no.

In the localhost I use this :

```
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

    storage_credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/storage')
storage_http = storage_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
storage_service = build("storage", "v1", http=storage_http)
```

This works fine, but when I deploy it in GAE, this don't work.

I have found a solution with this :

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

storage_credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  "463239370591-kvr7qpa2k5ee5jgdjgmk9ohc3ao3gve5@developer.gserviceaccount.com", key,
  scope=("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/storage")
)
storage_http = storage_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
storage_service = build("storage", "v1", http=storage_http)
```

And with this code I have an error :

> AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/storage is not valid scope.

Some one can explain that?

**EDIT**

At the same time I use the same way to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery and I don't have problems!

Comment: are you using the Google Cloud Storage API? Or client library?

Comment: @Patrice I use the client library

Comment: cool. Anyway, looking into the docs https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication, seems like you're not using the proper scope...

Comment: But why can I use it with the "AppAssertionCredentials" ? This is stange no?

Comment: well you mention that AppAssertionCredentials works only on local devserver, which is NOT the same as the App Engine, so there might be your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) on Google Cloud Storage authentication, seems like you need one of these scopes :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
```

depending on what you want to do. You will need to make sure the API is enabled in your console, and also use the Cloud Storage JSON API :)

Comment: I'd assume it's full control, because read_write only seems to give access to data, not metadata

Comment: I gonna use full control because I need to delete some files. But I still have a problem : "Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
Do you know how to update that?

Comment: Normally, when you have follow up questions, you should open a new question, as Stack is meant to be a repository of Q and As, not a forum. In any case, I think you need to go to "console.developers.google.com", then click on your project, then on API, then enable the "cloud storage API"

Comment: Ok, thanks you for your help. The "cloud storage API" is enable and the problem still here.

Comment: Really? you enabled it and you're still getting that same exact error? that's... odd

Comment: Yes, it is enable since 2 month maybe !

Comment: I need to use "Google Cloud Storage JSON API". Now it works fine.
Thanks for the help

Comment: My pleasure :). Always happy to help people on the platform. In the meantime, I will update my answer to includce the JSON API :). Bonne journée! (ou soirée, vu le décalage entre France et Canada)